# Dynamic Linq nested Select on collection property

Tags: c#, linq, graphql, dynamic-linq

We are using GraphQL Dotnet in a dotnet core 5.0 API.

We have a relational data structure like this

```
Organisation --> (Zero or many) Employers --> (Zero or many) Departments.
```

In an attempt to optimise our database queries we are doing some parsing of the query and hoping to limit the fields returned by SQL using [dynamic linq](https://dynamic-linq.net/).

They have some pretty basic examples like this

```
 var resultDynamic = context.Customers
             .Select("new { City, CompanyName }")
             .ToDynamicList();
```

So you can select `Customers.City`, and `Customers.CompanyName` to a new dynamic object list.

This is not far off what we want to do, however, some of the properties we want to query are nested in collections.

for instance the following graphQL query

```
organisations {
  id,
  name,
  employers {
    addressLine1
    }
  }
}
```

Should return a list of organisations with id and name populated, and their employers with only the addressline1 populated.

If our query is `Database.Organisations.Include(x => x.Employers);` graphql parses this fine, and we return the correct information. However, if you inspect the SQL, it's getting every field for organisation, and every field for employers, and GQL is basically trimming the data client side.

Using dynamic linq I can do this

```
Database.Organisations.Select("new Organisation {id, name}");
```

and it works great, returns the organisation with id and name populated, and those are the only SQL fields in the SQL select statement.

But as soon as I try to Select the addressLine1 field of employers I hit a bit of a brick wall.

I can do this

```
Database.Organisatons.Select("new Organisation {id, name, employers}");
```

and it will only select the required fields from organisations, but all employer fields are selected (and GQL does the trimming client side) but I can't figure out a way to do `employers.addressLine1` so that the subquery in sql only selects the one field.

Trying things like `Organisations.Select("new Organisation {id, name, employers.name}");` just results in

```
No property or field 'name' exists in type 'List`1'
```

Which is obviously because I Employers is a List property and I am basically trying to get that (List).Name ... which doesn't exist.

Ideally I want to do this in this string based select format as i can build that up by parsing the GraphQL query and then I could only select the fields required from the child objects, but I have no idea what the format of that would be and can't find any examples.

Comment: Have tried something related to GraphQL and LINQ? For example https://github.com/EntityGraphQL/EntityGraphQL

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv no, I haven't ever seen that! Thanks so much for the link, will try it out now.

Comment: I found the answer in another post, for anyone coming across this... this answer provided the answer I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66330419/dynamically-generate-linq-select-with-nested-collection-properties/66334073#comment121600674_66334073

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible with `employers.Select(name)`.

Example in LinqPad:

```cs
void Main()
{
    Rooms.Dump();
    (Rooms.Where(r => r.Id == 3) as IQueryable).Select("new { name, RoomReservations.Select(CheckinDate) as CheckinDates }").Dump();
}
```

Results into:
[image]

And the generated SQL looks like (only the 'name' and the 'CheckinDate' are selected in the query):

```sql
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 3
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[Name], [t1].[CheckinDate], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Reservations] AS [t2]
    WHERE [t2].[RoomId] = [t0].[Id]
    ) AS [value]
FROM [Rooms] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Reservations] AS [t1] ON [t1].[RoomId] = [t0].[Id]
WHERE [t0].[Id] = @p0
ORDER BY [t0].[Id], [t1].[Id]
```

--> Note that I tried to make a GraphQL library which uses DynamicLinq, however not all logic is supported. You can take a look here:
https://github.com/StefH/GraphQL.EntityFrameworkCore.DynamicLinq